# Problem with meta.sustainability certificate & HTTPS login

Tags: bug, status-deferred

If I try to connect to https://meta.sustainability.stackexchange.com with Firefox, I get dire browser warnings about invalid certificates. https://sustainability.stackexchange.com is fine, though.

This makes it impossible to log in to Meta if using the HTTPS Everywhere addon. This isn't specifically about my difficulty logging in - I can easily turn that addon off and do it without SSL - but is there something that should be fixed with the certificate that is used?

> meta.sustainability.stackexchange.com uses an invalid security
> certificate.
>
> The certificate is only valid for the following names:
> *.stackexchange.com , stackexchange.com , meta.stackexchange.com , *.meta.stackexchange.com , *.stackoverflow.com , stackoverflow.com , serverfault.com , stackauth.com , sstatic.net , meta.serverfault.com ,
> superuser.com , meta.superuser.com , stackapps.com ,
> openid.stackauth.com
>
> (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known problem and unfortunately there isn't much we can do about it at the moment.
The Stackexchange team is working on SSL support, but this is work in progress and officially none of the (meta) sites support SSL yet.

More information about this can be found in [this meta.stackoverflow question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216384/164138) or in [Nick Craver's blog on the 'Road to SSL'](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/)